# Are all pork in supermarket previously frozen? Where can I get fresh ones?

Tags: meat, pork, fresh, frozen

Are all pork in supermarket previously frozen? Where can I get fresh ones? Is there a way to easily tell visually if a meat has been previously frozen?

Comment: this is really 3 questions. The first two depend hugely on where you live. The second one is far too broad and is probably off topic as a shopping question. The last one, how to determine if you're being offered meat that was previously frozen, might be ok but it would be good to expand it a little. I recommend editing your question to focus on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find a **local butcher**. They can sell you never-frozen meat, and may carry different breeds of pig than your supermarket does. (Comparing pork from a butcher and pork from a supermarket is more practical than discussing hypothetical pork anyway.) I find the difference (and the value of my butcher) higher for pork than any other meat the supermarket carries. (The butcher also sells goat, duck, and other things I can't get at the supermarket.) Of course, depending on where you live you may not be able to find a butcher, or the difference from the supermarket may be stronger or weaker than it is where I live.

A tip: the cool trendy new butchers are on the Internet. I follow mine on Twitter to be the first to know when specific products are available. A good butcher drowns you in information about the product: not just whether it was frozen, but the breed, what it ate, exactly where the farm is, the farmer's children's names - they want to tell you all this if you want to know it. Mine gives me brochures from the farm with pictures of the fields and buildings and people.

Tip 2: my butcher's prices are roughly double the supermarket's. I just buy half as much: we 're happier eating half a delicious steak or chop than a whole boring one. We were probably eating overly large portions before anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are fresh ones if that supermarket has a butcher to "butch" the pig because the meat is normally good for only that day, or else the pork are either frozen or previously frozen. Normally one the package it would be labeled as "frozen" instead of fresh, but I would normally judge by the bloody liquid coming out from the meat since fresh meat usually hold the liquid much better.

Comment: meat can keep for longer than one day refrigerated